# Check comma from pandas columns and if it exist remove it and divided by 100 Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have the following simple data frame:

df

```
Test
3454,23
65
98,50
```

I want check whether comma or dot (.) exist and if it exist remove it and divided by 100.

The result seems like below.

```
Test
3454.23
65
98.50
```

I have tried this.

```
df['Test'] = (df['Test'].str.replace(',', '')/100)
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anyone help on this in Pandas? If have a solution something similar, you can indicate me the link.

Comment: Why not just replace `,` with `.`? Why the math?

Comment: What is the source for the dataframe? A csv/text file or something else? This may be an XY problem.

Comment: Looks like you should read csv with `thousand=','` option

Comment: Agreed with @takendarkk, just replace comman by dot..

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.str.contains` to define condition  and then

```
np.where(condition, outcome if condition true, outcome if contion false)
```

code below:

```
df['Test']=np.where(df['Test'].str.contains('\,'),df['Test'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)/100,df['Test'])

     Test
0  3454.23
1       65
2     98.5
```

Or use pandas mask to isolate where condition exist and apply multiply

```
df['Test']=df.Test.mask(df['Test'].str.contains('\,'),df['Test'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)/100)
```

or use pandas where

```
df['Test']=df.Test.where(~df['Test'].str.contains('\,'),df['Test'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)/100)
```